# Reading multiple rows from a csv in php

Tags: php, csv

How do i read two rows simultaneously from the csv file and perform operations.
My Logic is something like this

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    $j=1;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $i;
    while ($j <= $i+1) {
        echo $j;
        $j = $j+1;
    }
    $i = $i+1;  
}  
?>
```

Am trying to replicate the same logic while reading the csv Files, but for some reason am not getting two rows of data

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bpcl");
$filename = "test.csv";
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$file1 = fopen($filename, "r");
$i = 1;
while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $j = 1;
    echo $getData[1];
    while ((($getData2 = fgetcsv($file1, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) || ($j <= $i+1)) {
        echo $getData2[1];
        $j = $j+1;
    }
    $i = $i+1;

}

?>
```

My current days data depends on previous day,so i need two rows of data while traversing across the entire csv.Looking for some help here

Comment: If your logic depends on previous days, why not keep track of the previous day in your while loop? No need to read the file twice.

Comment: I need my logic to read the entire csv file having two rows in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to open the file twice or have two loops, all you need to do is read the csv in your while loop and then always store this record in the previous days data at the end of the loop.  Then if the previous data is set, you can work with this...

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bpcl");
$filename = "test.csv";
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$previousDay = null;
while ($currentDay = fgetcsv($file)) {
    echo "today = ".$currentDay[0].PHP_EOL;
    if ( $previousDay != null ) {
        echo "yesterdays = ".$previousDay[0].PHP_EOL;
    }

    $previousDay = $currentDay;
}
```

If you wanted to start with two days worth of data, then load the previous days before the loop...

```
$previousDay = fgetcsv($file);
```